# Security issue - Best way to store user details in iOS and max amount of data stored in KeyChain

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, nsuserdefaults, keychain

I am making a app where I need to store some login details.

I searched over internet and found usage of `NSUserDefaults` has some security issue.

As for `keychain`, how much data can I store for a single app?

The other option using `sqlite` also has some security issue.

About application update, how can I preserve data in the next application update.

So which one should I go for?

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` is a big NO for storing any secure data.

If it is only pertaining to user's username & password,i.e sensitive information, then `Keychain` is the best thing to use.

For other kinds of data(not sensitive) you can use `Core Data` to store information.

When an update takes place, you can explicitly copy data that is present & import it to your update.

`Keychain` data as such remains available to the app, after an update.

Comment: I want to store some string length of 6 to 25. How much I can save?

Comment: Point is how much do you want to save? What exactly is your use case?

Comment: You mean 330 strings, where each string is 6 to 25 characters? Mind sharing an example to make it more clear?

Comment: Yes I mean 330 strings each of 6 to 25 character.

Comment: all the 330 strings are sensitive data?

Comment: Yes they are. it may be weird but I need to take protection for those string.

Comment: Why not encrypt them & store in a sql db?

Comment: I was thinking something like that, but I need to keep that data in next update. If I update my app then will the data will remain same?

Comment: read my answer!! You can make sure you are copying the data that is present during an update!!

Comment: Thanks man, but can you describe how to import data in update? For different users data will be different.